# Using Date in Where Clause

Tags: oracle, sql-update

I am trying to place a date in a where clause.  I want to update all rows in which the date column is before or after a certain date.  How do I specify that I only want to update these columns.  Here is the coding that I have so far (not including specific column names):

```
update table1
set column1 = value
where (select date from table2) < date;
```

Am I on the right track?

Also, could someone please explain the difference between SQL and PL/SQL.  I am taking a class in PL/SQL at the moment.  Whenever I post a question on this forum I say that I have a question in PL/SQL, but the people who answer my question say that a certain function - update/if/case/etc. - is a SQL statement and not a PL/SQL statement.  What is the difference?

-Neil

Comment: I should mention that the way that I wrote the date in the where clause is: TO_DATE(01/02/2012);  Is that the correct way to write a date data type?

Comment: PL/SQL is exclusively used for stored procedures (functions, triggers). SQL is (essentially) anything you write outside of a stored procedure. This is all very well documented in the manual

Comment: You start learning SQL and eventually go to PL/SQL and advanced PL/SQL.

Comment: Which of the dates in your `where` clause have you specified like that? Neither would really make sense; if the first one then the subselect is pointless, if the second then... well, the subselect is pointless too, but you'll also either update all or no rows in table 1. And using a fixed date you should specify the format as `to_date('01/02/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY')` (or `MM/DD/YYYY` depending on your locale), or as ANSI standard `date '2013-01-02`. Plus, [overview of PL/SQL from the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/overview.htm). PL/SQL is SQL plus procedural stuff...

Comment: SQL is a 4GL and PL/SQL is a 3GL. PL/SQL allows SQL to be embedded natively, but generally the SQL in PL/SQL is not considered part of the PL/SQL language; it's more helpful to consider them separate languages with distinct (but complementary) features and capabilities.

Answer (score 3):

Your update statement

```
update table1
set column1 = value
where (select date from table2) < date;
```

is correct and it will work but only if the inner query `(select date from table2)` returns a single row. If you are trying to compare to specific date you don't need the inner query, for example:

```
update table1
set column1 = value
where to_date('01/02/2012', 'DD/MM/YY') < date;
```

You can adjust date format mask to whatever format of data you prefer. `to_date` will convert from char to date type, and `to_char` will do the opposite.

SQL is a standardized query language that is supported by all compliant relational databases (with some proprietary extensions sometimes). SQL is not a programming language. PL/SQL is a procedural programming language that is supported on Oracle only (Postgres has similar syntax). PL/SQL is SQL + regular programming language features like conditional statements (if/else), loops (for), functions and procedures and such. PL/SQL is used whenever it's too difficult or impossible to get some data using SQL solely.

Comment: And if you're not using Oracle, but SQL Server, then "PL/SQL" equivalent is T-SQL in SQL Server (stored procedures).

Answer (score 0):

As Aleksey mentioned, your query is correct but you need to either [1] set conditions around the sub-SQL to only return ONE record or [2] make sure the data in tabl2 only has ONE record when it runs.

ie

If you have to refer to data from another table in your WHERE clause consider explicit joins (example in SQL Server) ...

```
update t1
set t1.column1 = value -- <-- some arbitary value here I assume?
from table1 t1
   inner join table2 t2
      on (t2.key = t1.key) -- you need to specify the primary keys of the tables here
where t2.date < t1.date
```

That way you are not assuming table2 has only one record. It can have many records as long as they relate to table1 via their keys/indexes and the WHERE clause simply makes sure you only UPDATE based on data from table2 that has a date LESS THAN the date in table1.